# exec ssh file using php on same VPS

Tags: php, unix, ssh, exec, vps

I'm trying to launch a ssh file via php on same VPS, and I've had some problems with this.

When I connect to VPS via Putty screen "nosaukums" doesn't show in screen list, but all is working with `sh` file launching.

```
exec('cd /home/galvena/gameserveris ; screen -dmS nosaukums sh start.sh);
```

What could be wrong?

I have a second question. When I try to turn off a screen via php I get the error

> Must be connected to a terminal

when trying to execute the following:

```
exec('cd /home/galvena/gameserveris ; screen -r nosaukums ; stop');
```

Comment: Do you have any commands referencing `screen` in .profile?

Comment: php running in a webserver has no controlling terminal for screen to attach to. you can't reattach from within an exec call, much less from within a php script running under a webserver context.

Comment: @Marc B not as simple as using `shell_exec` or something is it?  Is there a way to emulate a legit terminal session?

Comment: no. php's running under apache, which is running as a daemon. there's no terminal involved. there's some chatter about it [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-send-a-command-to-a-screen-session-625015/), but unless something's changed since that '08 discussion, what you want isn't possible

Comment: Could you help us understand why you are trying to run gnu screen from php? There is most likely a more straightforward approach to what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see the reason of running this deamon in another screen. What you can do instead is create a simple shell script in the init.d folder with stop and start commands as you already have them. Then from php you can just call something like `system('service your_service_name stop/start');` Example of such script for a java solr deamon can be seen here: http://rc98.net/solrinit

You can also use `ps -aux | grep nosaukums` to check if its running. I am pretty sure also you can get the pid of that service with a unix command which unfortunately i dont know, but some googling will def show it and then just run `exec('kill PID');`

That just of the top of my head. Hope it helps...

Note the service command might require root priviledges so you may just put the script elsewhere and run it manually or just implement it directly in php...